# Regarding the Unix command "wc" what is considered as a word?

Tags: unix, cpu-word, wc

The command `wc` provides `lineCount`, `wordCount`, and `charCount`. I am writing a program that simulates the wc command as it takes a file and spits out the 3 properties. Line count is easy because if it sees `\n` it will `++lineCount` and if a char exists and it's not EOF, it will `++charCount`. But what does word mean? What separates words, whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

This is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html):

> The *wc* utility shall consider a word to be a non-zero-length string of characters delimited by white space.

The man page for `wc` on my system (Ubuntu 17.04) is similar:

> A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.