# C/C90/Counting words in large text file

Tags: arrays, c, c89

I have a text file which consists of about 30000 words. My goal is to count the actual number of the words (keep in mind that multiple punctuation marks and consecutive spaces are included, as well as words connected with `-` (for example `three-legged`), so counting just the spaces isn't correct).

I have managed to count the total characters but I am struggling with the words.
Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

char *getfile(void);
void stats(char *filename);

int main() {
    char *file;
    file = getfile();
    stats(file);
    return 0;
}

char *getfile(void) {
    char *filename;
    FILE *fp;
    filename = malloc(SIZE);

    printf("Enter the name of the text file: ");
    scanf("%49s", filename);

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    printf("\n");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("The entered file does not exist.");
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("The file exists.");
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return filename;
}

void stats(char *filename) {
    int cnt = 0, space = 0, lines = 0;
    int c;
    int count = 0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    while (((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)) {
        cnt++;

        if (c == ' ') {
            space++;
        }
        if (c == '\n' || c == '\0') {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nTotal characters in file: %d", cnt);
    printf("\nTotal characters (excluding spaces) in file: %d", cnt - space);
    
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Curiously, why code to a 33 year old standard C89 and not C11, C17, ...?

Comment: Why `scanf("%50s",filename);` , yet only allocate `SIZE 30`?

Comment: read each line then `strtok` it giving `strtok` the correct 'whitespace' delimiters https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html

Comment: what is the word? Is number a word? Is something like `@#$%^$%$` a word?

Comment: @pm100 hoe many words `,@,,,@,,,`?

Comment: Word definition as in POSIX (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816519/18980756)? Implementation available at https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-68/wc/wc.c.auto.html

Comment: @0___________ no idea, but the approach is still the same, read a line , chop it iup with strtok

Comment: There is no single definition of the term "word" acceptable to everyone in all situations, so you need to state which *exact* definition you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a list of all the chars that can separate between words, and count every sequence of separating characters.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having trouble is you have no *state*. That is, classifying context about what came before. You can use other methods to break the file into words, but a [state-machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) is simple and fast. As suggested in the comments and by other answers, you need two states, a white-space came before, and a word character came before. It's sort of like the one-bit derivative, with rising edge, white-space space to word, as a the thing you count.

Stripping off most of the extraneous stuff, this might be how you do a state machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buf[16384 /*50*/]; /* 50 is small. */
    enum { WHITE, WORD } state = WHITE;
    size_t cnt = 0, lines = 0, words = 0, nread, i;
    do { /* Fill `buf`. */
        nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stdin);
        if(ferror(stdin)) { perror("wc"); return 1; }
        cnt += nread;
        for(i = 0; i < nread; i++) { /* Char-by-char in `buf`. */
            unsigned char c = buf[i];
            /* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace */
            switch(c) {
            case '\n':
                lines++; /* Fall-though. Doesn't handle CRs properly. */
            case '\0': case ' ': case '\f': case '\r': case '\t': case '\v':
                state = WHITE;
                break;
            default:
                if(state == WORD) break;
                state = WORD;
                words++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(nread == sizeof buf);
    printf("Total characters in file: %lu\n", (unsigned long)(cnt - lines));
    printf("Total lines in file: %lu\n", (unsigned long)lines);
    printf("Total words in file: %lu\n", (unsigned long)words);
    return 0;
}
```

I off-loaded some work on the hosted-environment for brevity, `./wc < file.txt` and I used [a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13225014/2472827).